# Laravel 5.1 404 not found on apache server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have currently hosted laravel 5.1 application to my 1and1.com server and I am facing a 404 not found errors to all my routes except for the root route i.e www.example.com/server/

The root route is working with get request but all the other routes are coming as 404 not found , everything is working good in localhost.

**My application folder structure:**

- -example.com

  - -server

    - App
    - database
    - config
    - storage
    - .env
    - .htaccess
    - index.php
    - server.php

as you can see that I have removed the default laravel public folder and moved the contents to root.

**My .htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]   RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]  </IfModule>
```

**My Index.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**Server.php**

```
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */
$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.''.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'index.php';
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function(){
        echo'test';exit();
    });//test

Route::get('/s', function(){
        echo'testss';exit();
    });//test
```

now if you see that the first route is working fine, but when I do www.example.com/server/s this gives 404 not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you host your laravel application on a shared server, you need to separate the public folder.

All the contents of public folder should go to `public_html` folder of the server, while all the other folders need to go on root folder..

So, to get you going, first make a directory called `laravel-app` in your server root. Inside this folder, upload all the folders and files but do not upload the `public folder`.

Once all the files are uploaded, upload the contents of `public` folder to `public_html` folder.

Now, you need to tell laravel that you have changed the default structure of the folders. In order to do that, open `index.php` file which is located inside `public_html` folder.

Replace this line:

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

with this line:

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel-app/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel-app/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Now, re-upload the index.php file, and you should get the desired output.

Hope this helps you out. Happy Coding. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks this was great advice. I dont have access to sudo so this worked as a great alternative

Answer (score 6):

If your project migrated to the new server it could be in case if you use default project document root configuartion so it could be disabled to read your .htaccess file by default. You need to change AllowOverride option from "None" to "All" (in example) option value in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` (in case if centos):

```
<Directory /var/www/html/public>
    ...
    AllowOverride All
    ...
</Directory>
```

Then reload your server to apply changes

```
sudo service httpd reload
```

Answer (score 6):

in addition to Alex's answer, if you're running **apache**, try to

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and reload apache

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Hope this helps!